# String splitting

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string a such:

```
String str = "Kellogs Conflakes_$1.20";
```

How do I get the preceding values before the *dollar (*$) sign.

N.B: The prices could be varied say $1200.

Comment: You almost win the laziest poster award for the day. I think the only one who beat you simply posted their hw question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the substring using substring and the index of the $ character.

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('$'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.split(String s) which creates a String[].

```
String str = "Kellogs Conflakes_$1.20";              //Kellogs Conflakes_$1.20
String beforeDollarSign = String.split("$").get(0);  //Kellogs Conflakes_
```

This will split the String str into a String[], and then gets the first element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this for split `str.split("$")` and store it on an array of `String`.

```
String[] split = str.split("$");
```

And then get the first position of the array to get the values that you have before the `$`

```
System.out.println(split[0]); //Kellogs Conflakes_
```

At the position 1 you will have the rest of the line:

```
System.out.println(split[1]); //1.20
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

String str = "Kellogs Conflakes_$1.20";

String[] abc=str.split("\ \$");

for(String i:abc)

```
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

after this you can easily get abc[0]